# Is there a way to move the cursor to a label definition in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, labels

I wonder if there is a direct way to move the cursor (in a.tex file) to where a label is defined in TexStudio. Currently, I have to go to the pdf file first, and then move to the label definition and go back to the source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press with the right mouse button on the command `\ref{def}` and choose in the context menu: *jump to the definition*.
Alternative type: Ctrl+Alt+f.